# Is there a way of identifying the values of explanatory variables in a logistic regression at the end of a function?

Tags: r

I have a matrix called all.confusion.tables which contains a table of predicted values versus actual values for explanatory variables.
I then apply a misclassification rate function to this and it gives me an output which looks like

```
[1] 0.2105263 0.2631579 0.3157895 0.4210526 0.2105263 0.5000000 0.2105263 0.4210526
```

This output is the misclassification rate of each explanatory variable `("age","lwt", "race", "smoke", "ptl", "ht","ui","ftv")`in a logistic regression data set. Is there any way of identifying which variable each value corresponds to? Is there a specific piece of code that I can use that will show the names of each explanatory variable throughout a function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple stuff:

```
x <- rnorm(8) # some dummy data
setNames(x, c("age","lwt", "race", "smoke", "ptl", "ht","ui","ftv"))
```